# How to write an if statement about data attributes in R

Tags: r, igraph

I have network data in `igraph` with multiple attributes, n=943.

There is an attribute called `Border` that states whether or not a node represents a border crossing. The values are either Yes (x5) or NA (x938), class = NULL. The name of the graph object is `g`.

The statement I want to write should do the following: IF the value of the Border column = "Yes," return the names of those nodes (from the column $name). Result should be a list of five names.

This is the code I tried:

```
if (V(g)$Border == "Yes") {
  print (V(g)$name) 
}
```

It returns nothing along with the following warning message:

Warning message:

> In if (V(g)$Border == "Yes") { :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

What am I doing wrong? (I am very new to R).

Comment: Use `==` to test for equality, not `=`.

Comment: I now understand the = vs ==, but there is a new warning message.

Comment: `V(g)$Border` is a vector, not a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by sub-selecting the names you want.

```
V(g)$Name[which(V(g)$Border == "Yes")]
```